# Two Different SQL Query in One Page

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to perform two queries in one page. And results of these should be separate.

My code is like:

```
$artistList_sql = "CALL artistListele()";
$artistList_result = $mysqli->query($artistList_sql);

if($artistList_result->num_rows > 0){
  while($sanatci = $artistList_result->fetch_assoc()){
    /* bla bla */
  }
}

$catList_sql = "CALL kategoriListele()";
$catList_result = $mysqli->query($catList_sql);

if ($catList_result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $catList_result->fetch_assoc()) {
    /* bla bla */
  }
}
```

However, it doesn't work. First one runs perfectly, second one does nothing. What could be the problem?

Comment: Maybe error in your functions of SQL? Where do you define them?

Comment: I can use these stored procedures separately without problem. artistListele -> `SELECT * FROM ses_artist ORDER BY artist_name ASC` and kategoriListele() -> `SELECT * FROM ses_cat ORDER BY cat_order ASC`